# Rollback Salt-stack version

Tags: installation, saltstack

I've been using salt-stack version 0.17.4 for a while on a CentOS server. I installed salt on a new server by going to the saltstack website, adding the rpm and using a yum install salt-minion and was brought to version 2012.1.0. Is there a way to rollback salt to previous version i've been using?

Comment: Would you care to enlighten us to more details? Server OS, installation method, etc.?

Comment: updated the question with more information @EEAA